# Out of ideas, MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, android, mysql

This is one of my firts ever codes in android,
Please be forgiving :D

I Have this code:

https://pastebin.com/Wbz26gW7

The app runs, no errors, but it cant connect to the database...

and writes this at the logcat:

```
myapplication W/System.err: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

I Searched all over the internet for help but no success :(((

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question. Do not expect us to follow third-party links. Also, can you post the entire stack trace for this error?

Comment: You might want to check your database url a bit more closely. There is a pretty glaring error there.

Answer (score 1):

From your pastebin

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql11.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sqluname?autoReconnect=true", "sqldbname", "sqlpwd");
```

From the DriverManager docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

```
static Connection getConnection(String url)
static Connection getConnection(String url, Properties info)
static Connection getConnection(String url, String user, String password)
```

It appears you've mixed up your username and database name in your connect method. In other words, try

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql11.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sqldbname?autoReconnect=true", "sqluname", "sqlpwd");
```

Comment: Yeah i accidently mixed it up, but i just checked and in that hosting the db user name and the db name itself are actually identical...
That means that in the code itself it is actually right and not messed up... :(

Comment: Are you able to access the database any other way? Do you have a backend web console or something?